# Send SMS as background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing, background-task

I am developing a mobile application which sends SMS alert when device enter to a particular geofence as a background task. How can I send SMS alert in background. Following code is used to send SMS in app, as most of the resources explains which needs human interference. How can it be done in background without any interference.

```
 var message = new ChatMessage();
 message.Recipients.Add(item.PhoneNumber);
 message.Body = "School Service is few miles away from your home";
 await ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(message);
```

Comment: Any suggestion that I can notify the user without sending SMS?

Comment: Toast notification http://blog.rajenki.com/2014/04/trigger-background-task-using-geofence-windows-phone-8-1/

Comment: Is it possible to send toast notification to other devices?

Comment: take a look at push notifications

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use a chatmessage and send an sms in the background.  Only work around is to use a web service like twilo which lets you send an sms via a rest call.

Comment: Any suggestion that I can notify the user without sending SMS?

Answer (score 1):

The Best option to send notification in this case is toast notification form your background task. here is an example to toast notification. You can use this when your geo fencing task gets executed.

```
Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastXml = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
string toastMessage = "School service is fee miles away from home";
                        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(notificationmember.FullName + " " +toastMessage));

Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
((Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");
((Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "Main.xaml);

Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification toast = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(toastXml);
toast.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(36000);
//toast.SuppressPopup
toast.Failed += Toast_Failed; // handle faile state

Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It can't.

You cannot send SMS in the background.

Your only option is to find webservice that sends free SMS in your country and send messages this way.

Comment: Any suggestion that I can notify the user without sending SMS?

Comment: What about notifications in the Action centre?

Comment: Is it possible to send notifications to other devices?